# What is the difference between UX, CX, and BX?

Tags: terminology

I have been researching the relationship between User Experience (UX), Customer Experience (CX), and Brand Experience (BX) and found different definitions.

- [One says UX is the subset of CX and CX is a subset of BX.](https://uxplanet.org/what-makes-your-brand-experience-better-ux-or-cx-77818a137b53)
- [One says partial of them are intersected.](https://www.alessiobresciani.com/digital-marketing/the-difference-between-user-experience-ux-and-customer-experience-cx/attachment/differencebetweencxux/)
- [One says CX is the biggest unit, not BX.](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/cx-brian-solis-new-x-book-nicole-strong?published=t)

**Which concept is correct?**

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: There is also apparently a HX (Human eXperience)... :p

Comment: The difference is between getting work done and worrying about definitions.

Answer (score 3):

Just based on the four that we are discussing, it is easy to apply some tests for exclusivity.

- Not all users are customers (i.e. paying users), while all customers would probably be users.
- All UI form part of the user experience, but not all user experience is confined to the UI (e.g. physical stores)
- Brand experience (which dictates aspects of the product experiece, which requires a UI) can be incorporated into the user experience, customer experience and UI, while the UI, CX and UX all contribute to the brand experience.

Therefore, I would say that BX is inclusive of UX, which includes CX, and both UX and CX touches on UI (from a company's perspective).

However, from a user's perspective, there is no difference between BX, UX, CX except that there is the intangible aspect (not part of the UI) and the tangible aspect.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't single theory in the context of nomenclature - UX and UI started to differentiate in the industry - as occupations or scopes of activities.

However, the CX and BX context - may exist in a broader brand and marketing context.

---

**CX - Customer Experience**

Is how the client experience during a given process (e.g. purchasing a service, item, etc.)

That is, for example, defining touchpoints and examining reactions, feelings, emotions, conversion optimization.

Shops take care of all the senses (smell, sight, hearing)

---

**UX - User Experience**

How the user experience in a digital context - using a software product.

---

**UI - User Interface**

it's how the interface is designed (architecture, usability, interactions) - there is no reference here to behavioral psychology or cognitive science like in the UX case.

---

**BX - Brand Experience**

honestly - I hear the first, but by deduction I think it is the widest and associated with the brand in all circumstances (ads, references, reviews, image on the internet)

---

When it comes to scopes(there will be divergent opinions of course) - :

BX ∈ CX ∈ UX ∈ UI

Comment: I would change the order from `BX ∈ CX ∈ UX ∈ UI`  into  `BX ∈ UX ∈ CX ∈ UI` because every customer is a user, but not all users are customers. Hence the UX is broader than the CX.

Comment: User experience isn't confined to digital products; it does include human-computer interaction but there is far more to it than just that.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is in **what** is experienced by **who**:

### Brand experience

**What:**
How the whole (presentation of a) brand is experienced (product designs, advertisements, tone of voice, promotions at certain events)

**Who:**
Everyone who knows about the brand is experiencing it somehow

### User experience

**What:**
How the product operates, functions, behaves, looks, feels etc. is experienced

**Who:**
Any user

### Customer experience

**What:**
All "side-effects" of being customer of a company. Think about the whole experience around the support service, invoicing, a cloud storage/backup service that come with the product, notifications about updates etc.

**Who:**
A (paying) user who makes use of services of the company

---

A few examples of good and bad experiences of the three combined:

- A user finds that the product doesn't work as smooth (UX) as the adverisement promised (BX)
- A customer finds that the product is good (UX), but the support service is terrible (CX)
- A non-customer feels that the product is "not for him/her" while he/she belongs to the target group of the product (BX)
- A non-customer hears from a friend (BX) how easy to use a product is (UX)
- Someone decides to buy the product (BX) but finds out after the purchase that an account is needed before the product can be used (CX/UX)

So...

- Who experiences a brand doesn't have to have experience as a customer or user
- A customer experiences the brand and the product but also the after sales, services etc. of the company.
- A user is a customer* experiencing the brand and the product, and as part of that experience also the UI
- A user experiences more than just the UI, it can be sound, texture or even be the user's surroundings

The first image looks about right:

[image]

*Side note: There are situations where the customer isn't a user, but basically a user is always a customer (paying or not).

Answer (score 0):

UX as a subset of CX is pretty standard.

UX covers how a user interacts with a system or some other 'thing', for instance a e-commerce site or navigating yourself around a train station.

CX covers the above, and broader aspects of how they are dealt with. For instance the letter you will recieve after using the voter registration system, what the information desk will say and do to help you escape the train station of doom.

BX...this is not a common term. It could be overarching company image across different interactions and services...Though I would still class this under CX. Overall it seems to be a lot fluffier stuff. Less about active experience and more about subtle nudging towards making you try out the CX independent of the quality of the CX itself.

So I'd say UX is a subset of CX.  BX is its own thing that is marketing, not UX.